# Is there any in-memory scanner which is similar to java.util.Scanner for reading a line of string?

Tags: java, io, nio

I have been trying to make an in-memory string processing application for my assignment.
So, I thought that loading the whole string into memory, and then parsing a string which is loaded into memory.

For this, at first I made an byte-string parser which acts same as scanner but using CharBuffer. (Whole string is loaded into memory) But it is not fast even disk-based string parser.

At that time, I found that CharBuffer implements Readable, so I tried to use scanner like this:

```
FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mapped_buffer =
             channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
CharBuffer buffer = decoder.decode(mapped_buffer);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(buffer).useDelimiter("\n");
```

But it is similar or even slower than just disk-based scanner. 
The disk-based program's sample code is below:

```
File target = new File(target_path);

Scanner scan = new Scanner(target);
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        line = scan.nextLine();
        ... }
```

Everyone thinks that in-memory processing is much faster than disk-based processing.
To achieve above performance, what should I consider to parse a string in memory?
Is it reasonable to use scanner to read in-memory string data?
Or is the scanner I use not read parsed line of string from memory?

Comment: My guess is,  the disk is the bottleneck. When you scan directly from disk, the OS is smart enough to read ahead while your code handles previous chunk.

Comment: @hyde What if the disk is the bottleneck, I already loaded whole string data into memory, so that bottleneck of disk is not a problem, right? What is your thought?

Comment: You are including the file read time in your measurement, or measuring just time to process data in memory, excluding the time to read it?

Comment: @hyde Just time to process is the matter of this program. Using the decoding step, it tooks some seconds to caching the whole string into data at the CharBuffer. But just processing time is somewhat slow, I mean it is even not faster than disk-based program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use Scanner at all? Scanner, CharsetDecoder, etc, are all going to be slow.

Especially if all you are reading is ASCII, you don't really need any of that.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
in.read(bytes);
in.close();

char[] text = new char[bytes.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    text[i] = (char)(bytes[i] & 0xFF);
}

for (String line : new String(text).split("\n")) {
    //
}
```

UTF-16 is only an extra step more complicated.

If you want to read line by line that's not all that complicated. I would still recommend against something like Scanner.

```
StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(1024);
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

int next;

boolean lb = true;

while ((next = in.read()) != -1) {

    if (next == 0xD || next == 0xA) {

        // skip if there are multiple line breaks
        if (lb) continue;

        lb = true;
        sendNextLineSomewhere(line.toString());

        // avoid new object creations
        line.delete(0, line.length());

    } else {

        lb = false;
        line.append((char)next);
    }
}

in.close();
```

One side note about ASCII line breaks is that there are two characters related to it. Line Feed (0xA) and Carriage Return (0xD). Some text editors (Windows Notepad for example) register a line break from a two character CR+LF combination. It's just a thing to keep in mind. If you don't take it in to account and your file originates from a program like that you'll get blank lines. And on the output side, if you don't write the CR+LF combo when you want a new line programs that want it won't read the file correctly.

Comment: Because the text file is so large at least 100MB.
Is that scale of file has some limitations when we try to deal with byte array?

Comment: Well you can either have it all in memory at once or not. Do you mean you only want to read line by line from the file? That's also fairly trivial to do.

Comment: Then I don't see a way to do it without just reading the file and looking for the line breaks as you go. I added an example for that.

Comment: I've tried your suggested method yesterday, but it is slower than scanner. I don't know why but I guess the slowness comes from the heavy text data in same hashmap structure. (I read a line from text and split the string using space delim and adding a word into hashmap, like wordcount)

Comment: In today's world of unicode text and myriad of char encodings, rolling your own scanner is generally a bad idea, unless it is a toy project or the purpose is to specifically learn low level encoded text processing. Also, "slow", by what meaningful measure?

Comment: Yeah hyde, you are right. But I think in-memory application has to be somewhat faster than disk-based application. So, I guess even I opened scanner object with CharBuffer class obj, there is something goes wrong and it is not working on in-memory manner.

Comment: @hyde The OP's file is 100MB, that's why it's slow. And if all they need is to read ASCII there's no point in over-complicating things.

Comment: @YoonMinNam I think what you could do is remove certain parts of the code and find out what is slowing you down. IE read the file without working with the map and that will tell you if the map is the slow part. Though it sounds like what you are doing is just not going to be particularly fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my approach for parsing a String sequential:

```
  byte[] msg = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
  ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(msg);

  InputSource saxInputSource= new InputSource(byteArrayInputStream);

  InputStream underlyingByteStream = saxInputSource.getByteStream();

  Reader reader = saxInputSource.getCharacterStream();

  StringBuffer segmentBuffer = new StringBuffer(512);

  // write a method for writing into the segmentBuffer
  int c = reader.read();

  while(c != -1){
      segmentBuffer.append((char) c);
     // do something.. in your case break; if \n appears
     c = readChar();
  }
```

Sry for the messy code this is just out of my memory. I hope you get the idea behind this, filling the StringBuffer with chars until a linebreak is reached. After that you can process the line and clear the StringBuffer, for calling the method again and filling it and so on... Just ask if you need more clarification.

EDIT:
Hm I dont really know what you actually want to achieve, but using the code below takes on my machine 0,389 seconds to read a 100 MB file. It also buffers the content into the memory.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
      }
      br.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. However, I used somewhat very large text file with random-generated file with above 100MB scale. Therefore, it is not possible to load every data into byte buffer. So, I used ByteBuffer or MappedByteBuffer in Java.nio, instead of using byte array.

Comment: But your method is not totally depends on data in memory, I think. I;ve tried to counting a word in a textbook file. But, that textbook is so large that disk-based method with 250MB textfile took nearly 20secs. But loading textfile into memory took just 0.7sec.